# find a string and get the previous string delimited by a comma

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I am new to UNIX.

How do I achieve the below

```
input: text1=ABC/text2=DEF
output: text1,text2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very exact in term of structure of the string you would like to convert. So I'm going to guess that your input characteristics are:

- Multiple `KEY=VALUE` pairs are provided in single line.
- Each pair will be separated from other pairs by `/` character.
- `/` must be placed only between pairs (not at the start or the end of string).
- No consecutive repetition of `/` is allowed.
- In each pair, key *cannot* be empty, but value can be empty (`=` is optional if value is empty).
- Each key and value cannot contain `=` and/or `/` character.

And you needed to extract *keys*, then output them delimited by comma...

---

#### Sed-based Approach (Cheat)

This can be done from your script by running your input through one-line `sed`-based search/replace operation:

```
sed 's/=[^/]*//g;y/\//,/'
```

- **Translation:** Remove all instances of *`=` together with consecutive non-`/` characters following it*; then, replace all `/` characters with comma.

Example code follows (should run on any POSIX shell, not just GNU Bash):

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is ssv-keys-sed.sh

echo -n "input: "
IFS= read -r INPUT
echo -n "output: "
echo "$INPUT" | sed 's/=[^/]*//g;y/\//,/'
```

Example run:

```
$ sh ssv-keys-sed.sh
input: keyA=valueA/  k e y B =/keyC/keyD=valueD
output: keyA,  k e y B ,keyC,keyD
```

---

#### Shell Script Approach (Full Parsing)

If you insist on doing this by using shell script-based *parsing* rather than substitution-based cheat above, you can toy with `IFS` word separator variable and `for` loop. Be sure to **take notice of quoting (and lack of thereof) in different contexts; this can make or break the program**, since we are tinkering with shell's internal word separator.

- If you use shell script variable unquoted, it values will be split by delimiters specified in `IFS` variable, then taken as multiple tokens.
- If you enclosed shell script variable by *double* quote, its value will be used as whole, not split.
- If you enclosed shell script variable by *single* quote, it will not be treated as variable; everything written inside single quote will taken literally.

Following script should run on any POSIX shell, not just GNU Bash...

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is ssv-keys-parse.sh

# Show input prompt
echo -n "input: "

# Read one line from standard input into variable INPUT,
# no parsing or escape-processing
IFS= read -r INPUT

# Prepare empty output variable OUTPUT
OUTPUT=""

# Set parsing separator for extracting pairs
IFS="/"
# Extract each pair
# ^ Note that all pairs will be extracted before the loop is run,
#   so separator set inside the loop won't effect pairs extraction.
for PAIR in $INPUT
do
    # Set parsing separator for extracting key
    IFS="="
    for KEY in $PAIR
    do
        # Stop at the first split part of key-value pair (i.e. key)
        break
    done

    # If this is not the first key in the output, append comma to the output
    if [ -n "$OUTPUT" ]
    then
        OUTPUT="$OUTPUT,"
    fi

    # Append the extracted key to the output
    OUTPUT="$OUTPUT$KEY"
done

# Emit output
echo "output: $OUTPUT"
```

Example run:

```
$ sh ssv-keys-parse.sh
input: keyA=valueA/  k e y B =/keyC/keyD=valueD
output: keyA,  k e y B ,keyC,keyD
```

---

P.S. My test runs are done with Debian Almquist Shell installed as `/bin/sh`, and `sed` being GNU sed.